# Ignore-regex for folder and subfolders in Sublime Text SFTP plugin

Tags: plugins, ftp, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I've been in some trouble getting the `ignore_regex` option working in the [Sublime SFTP](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) plugin for Sublime Text. I'm not that good with regex, though I guess this should be fairly easy

My folder structure is pretty simple:

```
main_folder  
│
├─── css  
│    │    some other files
│    │    in the \css folder,
│    │    etc..
│    │    
│    └─── sass  
│          │    some other files
│          │    in the \sass folder,
│          │    etc..
│          │    
│          └─── sass_subfolders 
│                   some other files 
│                   in \sass_subfolders,
│                   etc..  
├─── other_folders  
│
etc...
```

I'd like that everything in the `\sass` folder, and the folder itself, to be ignored by sftp for uploading/syncing.

I've tried also with the configuration suggested in this [post](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3416&start=90) on the sublime forum , specifing to exclude the .scss files, yet it keeps uploading/syncing upon save and so on..

Comment: I'm in exactly the same boat. I'd like to start using sublime full-time but there are only so many hours in the day to get workflow setup. I've a co-worker who is good with regex, if he gets back to me I'll post it here.

Comment: @pspahn that would be great! and you are totally right, setting up things for your workflow can take lots of time, still ST2 offer so much flexibility that it can replace quite easily a lot of ides with some tweaks, the right plugins, and (unfortunately for me :P)a good dose of coding/programming skill for your specific needs..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To have an entire directory ignored by sublime sftp add it to your ignore_regexes settings like so:

"/folder_name/"

I use it to ignore octopress which generates my blog but doesn't need to be on the remote server itself.  I also ignore the directory on the server that holds the generated blog, but doesn't live on my local machine in the same place.

This and a few more tips are [on the plugin's faq page](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/faq#Ignore).

Comment: Thank you for your input, with the code you specified it will ignore (finally) what's inside the folder and won't upload files nor sub-folders, still the folder specified _is_ created on the remote server, is this normal or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: No that's not normal.  The regex above should have ignored both the folder and the files inside.  Make sure to sync Local -> Remote changing the regex and make sure the sync_skip_deletes config is set to false. Sorry for the late reply by the way.

Comment: No worries, thx for answering back! Unfortunately I can't test with your new suggestion as I'm away from that working setup, I'll try and update as soon as i get back.

Comment: Ok got back and it seems you are right, i guess the issue was caused by not correct syncing, anyway syncing Local->Remote as you suggested fixed the thing! Thank you again! (for anyone wondering, you have to right click on a file in the sidebar, go to SFTP/FTP and there is sync Local->Remote)

Answer (score 6):

Applying the accepted answer, add the folder you want to ignore into the `ignore_regexes` array in `sftp-config.json`. But you also need to know the default settings of `ignore_regexes` first [wbond ref](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings#setting-ignore_regexes). For example, if you want to add "/folder_name/" folder, the final array will look like:

    `"ignore_regexes": ["\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\d?)?\\.json", "sftp-settings\\.json", "/venv/", "\\.svn", "\\.hg", "\\.git", "\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\.db", "desktop\\.ini", "/folder_name/"],`

Answer (score 0):

Just used this to remove a few folders from the sync settings (these are folders on the server that i don't want, i only wanted the files at the root level.)

"ignore_regexes": [
        "\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\d?)?\.json",
        "sftp-settings\.json", "/venv/", "\.svn/", "\.hg/", "\.git/",
        "\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\.db", "desktop\.ini","/MySQL/","/_admin/","/admin/"
    ],

is my setting for this, the folders i am ignoring are:
MySQL
_admin
admin

really helpful setting, it saved me downloading 100's of MB worth of data!

Answer (score -1):

Seems you should be able to just add in:

```
"ignore_regex": "(css/sass/|ignore/this/too)"
```

Comment: this is the first setup i tried, still when i save files in the `css/sass` folder these get uploaded, same happen when i sync the `css` folder, also the `sass` folder get counted.
Little question about the `|` character: does it mean sort of "new rule after this"? or something else?